How can create a module and add it to top menu in Vtiger 7, see picture
I'm new in Vtiger.
I want to create new module to send message in WhatsApp, And I need add it to menu I show in attached picture (Like sending Email should open a popup form to get a test or select a template message to send the number in whatsapp). Is there any simple example to help me.
I need to create this module not buy it...

Oh man, adding module to Vtiger top menu not super hard, but kinda confusing if you're new. So, first, you make the module, yeah? Like in /modules/ folder. Add all files there, PHP stuff. After that, go to database, table vtiger_tab. Add a new row for your module name. Make sure it has isentitytype=1, so Vtiger knows it's legit.
Then for menu, there's a table called vtiger_parenttab. You add your module to a category there, or it won't show in the top menu. If still invisible, clear cache or log out/in. About WhatsApp pop-up, you'll need API, like Twilio. Pop-ups? Use Vtiger’s JS modal things. Might take time, but works if you're patient.

Thanks alot. I know php and JS very well and have WhatsApp Api but new in Vtiger.  I need to khow the strature of Vtiger better

My question is in these tables  "vtiger_tab" and "vtiger_parenttab" if I have to call any function to show my popup form?

I found the answer.
put this code in php file on the root of crm path and run in webbrowser:
 <?php 
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Leads');
$moduleInstance->addLink('DETAILVIEW', 'Test1', 'index.php'); 
//$moduleInstance->deleteLink('DETAILVIEW', 'Test1', 'index.php'); //this is for delete

?>

